# Solr:Connection Lost when using data import handler to fetch data from postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

I am trying to index the data of size 70 million row. I am using data import handler to fetch the data form postgreSQL database. When I execute the full import command, after indexing around 3-5 million row, I see the error "Connection Lost". When I check the status of the solr instance in the server, I see that it is not active, it is dead, port is not open.

```
# service solr status`
```

> > Found 1 Solr nodes: 
> >      Solr process 45397 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.`

Then I need to restart the solr instance again every time it stops

```
# service solr start
```

> > Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]
> >     Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=47740). Happy searching!

I added the socket timeout parameters to jdbc driver parameters, and also increased all timeout parameters in solr.xml

Below is the my db-data-config.xml file.

```
`<dataConfig>
  <dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://ourdbserveripaddress:5432/dbname" user="username" socketTimeout="0" defaultRowFetchSize="10000" />
    <document >
       <entity name="solr_70m" query="SELECT id, myrecord from solr_70m">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="myrecord" name="myrecord" />
       </entity>
    </document>
 </dataConfig>`
```

After connection loss, we can search commited data.

Could you tell me what I am missing to load/index data of over 50million records?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the log? I'm also unfamiliar with any `defaultRowFetchSize` or `socketTimeout` settings and can't find them mentioned in the source.. There's `batchSize` and `maxRows` and a few settings related to transactions, but no "defaultRowFetchSize" as far as I can tell.

Comment: defaultRowFetchSize is a parameter for postgresDB, without that parameter, still I get connection lost problem. I tried to find the similar to batchSize which is parameter for mysql jdbc driver but not for postgres. https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html In the log file we cant catch the error except recovery error. In the log file it is written that java.io.EOFException
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.FastInputStream.readFully(FastInputStream.java:168)

Comment: But `defaultRowFetchSize` is [never read in the DIH code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/JdbcDataSource.java), so I'm not sure how it'd map over to the Postgres JDBC driver. My guess is that if you're going to give any specific parameters like that, they'll have to be part of the connection URL. `batchSize` is not MySQL specific, as it's read and marshalled into the `setFetchSize` method on statements.

Comment: According to [the jdbc documentation for postgresql's jdbc connect](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), the property you're thinking of is a parameter given in the connection URL.

Comment: You are right batchSize is not mysql specific. I removed socketTimeout="0" defaultRowFetchSize="10000" and added batchSize="-1", based on https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq  , but then now, nothing is getting indexed. Using defaultRowFetchSize doesn't not affect at all in an negative way as I could index  around 3-5 million record before connection lost. I think something which i don't knoe yet make solr instance to die.

Comment: I'd try something else than `-1` - that's probably more of a MySQL specific value. Using the default value should be fine (500), but you can try tuning it manually if necessary. There's even a specific suggestion for PostgreSQL running out of memory in the wiki page you linked: `<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://host/db" user="user" password="password" readOnly="true" autoCommit="false" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT"/>`

Comment: I don't think it is a memory issue. Yet I just tried with these parameters and after 3.2 million record again got "connection lost" :/ . One way or another we could get up to 13million. Yet never accomplished to import full data. most of the time we get error 3-5 million, but rarely, 6million, 13 million data get indexed too.

Comment: So, nothing logged on the postgres side either? Have you tried looking at what's happening over the network / the local socket? How about attaching a debugger/heap dumper to the JVM process and seeing how memory use happens? Attach a debugger to the exception you got and see what's on the stack at the moment..